# ifstream read only one text file in for loop

Tags: c++

i wrote this simple code to read 4 text file from my D directory, put it in string vector, then take those strings from vector one by one and show it to the user. problem is it reads contents of only first file and does not read contents of other files. what is wrong in it..... Thanks in advance

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::stringstream path;
    std::vector<std::string> vectorOfStrings;
    ifstream readFile;


    for(int i=1; i<= 4; i++)
    {

    path << "D:\\Text0"<< i <<".txt";
    readFile.open(path.str());

    if(readFile.is_open())
    {
        while(!readFile.eof())
        {
            getline(readFile, line);
            ss << line << "\n";

        }   
        ss<< "\n ***************************************\n";
        vectorOfStrings.push_back(ss.str());
        ss.str("");
        readFile.close();
        readFile.ignore();
        readFile.clear();
    }
    }


    ss << vectorOfStrings.at(0);
    cout<<ss.str();
    ss.str("");

    ss << vectorOfStrings.at(1);
    cout<<ss.str();
    ss.str("");

    ss << vectorOfStrings.at(2);
    cout<<ss.str();
    ss.str("");

    ss << vectorOfStrings.at(3);
    cout<<ss.str();
    ss.str("");

    return 0;
}
```

files located in my D drive are Text01.txt, Text02.txt, Text03.txt, Text04.txt

Comment: `while(!readFile.eof())` Whyyyyyyyyyyyyy?

Comment: _"does not read contents of other files. what is wrong in it"_ Not a good problem description. Did you step through your code in the debugger?

Comment: I'd love to know what "debugging" you did then because this is an extremely basic error that would have been caught with the most basic and trivial of debugging.

Comment: @Eliyahu-Shmuel: He isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn how to use a debugger.

```
path << "D:\\Text0"<< i <<".txt";
```

After the first iteration, `path`'s buffer contains "D:\Text01.txt".

After the second, it contains "D:\Text01.txtD:\Text02.txt"...

As `path` is a stream, you'll need to clear it in the same way you cleared your other streams.

You'd have seen this if you'd inspected the buffer's value, or if you'd output some text when the file could not be opened, or really just added any error reporting of any kind.

Comment: @Rem​​​​​​​​​​​y: Thanks for your correction, though I've reverted your subjective narrative style changes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help someone. and nececcerily do not use here if(readFile.is_open()). because it write twice to vector value of the current file

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include<iostream>
   #include<fstream>
   #include<string>
   #include<sstream>
   #include<vector>

   using namespace std;

 int main(){
   ifstream stream1;
   string str;
   vector<string> list;
   stringstream ss;
   stringstream path;
   stringstream res;

for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
path << "file" << i << ".txt";
stream1.open(path.str());

if(stream1.is_open())
{

        getline(stream1, str);
        cout << str << endl;
        ss << str << " \n ";
        list.push_back(ss.str());

    stream1.close();
}

path.str(string());
ss.str(string());
}

cout << " ----------------- " << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    ss << list.at(i);
    cout << ss.str();
    ss.str(string());
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the issue is that `path` isn't cleared after each loop.

Now, instead of explicitly "reset" that (and not only that) variable we can use a more general and useful concept call [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii):

> The “resource acquisition is initialization” technique. The basic idea
>   is to represent a resource by a local object, so that the local
>   object’s destructor will release the resource. That way, the
>   programmer cannot forget to release the resource... (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#finally)

For example, OP's code can be modified in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vectorOfStrings;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= 4; i++ )
    {
        std::stringstream path;
        path << "D:\\Text0" << i << ".txt";
        std::ifstream readFile(path.str());

        if ( !readFile )
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: Unable to open file " << path.str() << '\n';
            break;
        }
        std::string line;
        std::stringstream ss;
        while( getline(readFile, line) )
        {
            ss << line << "\n";
        }
        ss << "\n ***************************************\n";
        vectorOfStrings.push_back(std::move(ss.str()));
    }

    for ( const auto &s : vectorOfStrings ) {
        std::cout << s;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's helpfull.